# How to tweet in iPhone when app is closed or in background Process

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am making an application in which i have to show user location url in twitter, i have successfully integrated twitter api and url gets post whenever signed in and clicked tweet, however is there any way when user clicks on home button, then in background process url gets updated in twitter, please hep me regarding this issue

Comment: do you mean EVERY time home is clicked? or just on exit of your app?

Comment: no there will be a timer set in the application, and after certain time interval,it should post or tweet on user wall, i need some kind of help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

The [applicationWillResignActive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html): method will get called if the user hits the home button (or gets interrupted by a phone call, etc)

In that handler you could do a POST to Twitter.  I think that would be a small enough task that it wouldn't be disruptive or against the intended use of that method.

Comment: ok , its possible to post a tweet in background, i have searched a lot and have found in some post or blog that its not possible

Comment: I'm assuming you're just submitting a POST request to a URL containing the tweet data?  That *should* be OK in the applicationWillResignActive method, and even in the applicationDidEnterBackground method which is called afterwards, since it grants you 5 seconds to 'tidy up'.

Answer (score 0):

Since only certain activities are permitted in the background (location, music, etc)...you'd have to piggyback on one of those...since you're tweeting location it makes sense to use that one, so perhaps you could use signigificant location changes, and tweet on each locationDidUpdate?

Comment: thanks i have getting the url from the webserver which i have to post, i have saved the url link and when app goes into background after certain time interval it should again post the url

Comment: I don't think your timer will persist, you'll have to trigger the tweets with a location change...you COULD use full power location (startUpdatingLocation) and ignore all updates until some time interval has passed, but that'll be a big draw on battery, so if significant location changes is sufficient, I'd go with that...but if they're stationary, you won't get any tweets until they move again

Answer (score 0):

You can't post a request in the background every N minutes.

The only thing you can do is have some time when the app goes to the background to finish something you've started, like, say, if you started a download request and the user clicks the Home button, you have some time to finish the request.

One this time is done, your app is sleeping.

But you may register to have a notification that may wake up your app on significant location changes. This should be helpful if your aim is to tweet your position every time you move significantly.